# How to group-by for a column with the number of occurrences in a different column and count the frequency of the sentences in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, count, pandas-groupby

I have the below dataframe. I need to group-by with the number of occurrences in another column and segregate it.

- Firstly i need to group-by the "employee name "
- And for that particular employee, i need to count and segregate how many "Target classifications"
- Then I need to see the frequency of "notes" for that particular empolyee

  **Input :**

  ```
  ed_name    ed_employee_role    bn_note_text     word_count   Target_Classification
  ABC        RM                  abcd, efgh, ij   12           SufficientInfo
  XYZ        BM                  done             14           InsufficientInfo
  PQR        SM                  pqr, jji, bbb    10           SufficientInfo
  ABC        RM                  ajhd hju         9            SufficientInfo
  ABC        RM                  xyz pqr tv       16           SufficientInfo
  XYZ        BM                  done meeting     9            InsufficientInfo
  PQR        SM                  met              5            InsufficientInfo
  PQR        SM                  met              5            InsufficientInfo
  ```

  **Desired Output :**

  ```
  emp name : PQR  
  notes :
  pqr, jji, bbb   
  met     
  met     

  Count of Insuffient Info :          2
  Count of Suffiient info  :          1
  Frequency of repeating sentence :   2
  ```

  ---

  ```
  emp name : ABC  
  Notes:
  abcd, efgh, ij  
  ajhd hju    
  xyz pqr tv  

  Count of Insuffient Info :          0
  Count of Suffiient info             3
  Frequency of repeating sentence     0
  ```

  ---

  ```
  emp name : XYZ  
  Notes:
  done    
  done meeting    

  Count of Insuffient Info :          2
  Count of Suffiient info             0
  Frequency of repeating sentence     0
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create `DataFrame` by aggregate `bn_note_text` for number of duplicated values with `join` all text together with another DataFrame of size all catagories. Last [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) them together:

```
aggreg = [('repeat_no', lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False).sum()),
          ('text', ', '.join)]
df2 = df.groupby('ed_name')['bn_note_text'].agg(aggreg) 

df1 = df.groupby(['ed_name', 'Target_Classification']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
#slowier alternative in large df
#df1 = pd.crosstab(df['ed_name'], df['Target_Classification'])

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
  ed_name  InsufficientInfo  SufficientInfo  repeat_no  \
0     ABC                 0               3          0   
1     PQR                 2               1          2   
2     XYZ                 2               0          0   

                                   text  
0  abcd, efgh, ij, ajhd hju, xyz pqr tv  
1               pqr, jji, bbb, met, met  
2                    done, done meeting
```

Another solution with `list`s:

```
aggreg = [('repeat_no', lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False).sum()),
          ('text', lambda x: x.tolist())]
df2 = df.groupby('ed_name')['bn_note_text'].agg(aggreg) 
df1 = df.groupby(['ed_name', 'Target_Classification']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
#slowier alternative in large df
#df1 = pd.crosstab(df['ed_name'], df['Target_Classification'])

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
  ed_name  InsufficientInfo  SufficientInfo  repeat_no  \
0     ABC                 0               3          0   
1     PQR                 2               1          2   
2     XYZ                 2               0          0   

                                     text  
0  [abcd, efgh, ij, ajhd hju, xyz pqr tv]  
1               [pqr, jji, bbb, met, met]  
2                    [done, done meeting]
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working. However, I need the "ed_name" , "employee_role" and "bn_text" in my final result. How do I get that? 
I tried appending/merging but there's a lot of NaNs generated

Comment: @Anagha - one thing, output need DataFrame? Or prints?

Comment: it needs to be dataframe